# How to connect to SignalR server from ASP.NET Core server and keep it open?

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I have an ASP.NET Core back-end web server which does not run a SignalR server/hub. However, the back-end needs to connect to a SignalR hub as a client and keep that connection open all the time to keep some data in sync. How can I do that? I'm not sure IHostedService fits my purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IHostedService` is exactly intended for scenarios like these - when you have something running in background for the entire lifetime of your app (i.e. while the executable is running).

You can use [System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.clientwebsocket?view=netframework-4.8) to connect to the server from your application